# Transform is limited to border which I can't change

Tags: gimp, transform, borders

I have an object which is limited by black-yellow border
[image]
Then I surround it with cage transform markers
[image]
Then when I move those markers to do the transformation, the object is still limited by the border and I don't know how to change it. **How to change that black-yellow border?**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "border" indicates the layer boundary: nothing can happen outside of it.

But you can increase the layer size to cover the whole canvas with *Layer>Layer to image size*.